# browser hangs 'connecting'... then continues after ~30 secs

Tags: networking

Intermittently (5-10 times per day) my browser (Chrome and Firefox) hangs with the current status reading 'connecting...' then after 30 secs to 1-2 mins it continues normally.

There are no messages in /var/log/syslog and the hardware must be OK as I don't have this problem when running my dual-boot OS (Windows). Everything is up-to-date.
This happens with Firefox and Chrome. My Ubuntu laptop (on the same home network) does not have this problem so it's not a router issue. 
I tried changing the DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, but that did not help.

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue? Any suggestions much appreciated!

2015-01-05 12:50 - Update

I'll try updating the driver, but here's a question...

```
lspci | grep ether
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI     Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
dmesg | grep ether
[    1.770155] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
```

So, do I use the 8169 or the 8168 driver?

Comment: Here's a suggestion.  Please try booting your system to a cd/dvd of Ubuntu both of the version you are using, and just for kicks something previous, possibly 12.04 or 13.10.  I frequently use a 13.10 mini dvd as a test boot disk.  I'm suggesting you do this because if you don't have the problem from a cd/dvd then it suggests the problem isn't inherent to Ubuntu but something that's gone wrong with your installation and can hopefully be corrected.

Comment: @gyropyge: OK, that makes sense, but it won't really help me finding the current cause of the problem. I'd really like to somehow debug my current setup.

Comment: You asked for help.  You have the right to turn down help if you wish, but the art of diagnostics often requires multiple tests and multiple observations.  No single test is going to give you all the answers at once.  It is simply not possible.  It's not like I asked you to do something expensive and complicated.  If you comply with my suggestion and report back with observations we will continue.  Otherwise I will leave you to the next person who tries to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're just having trouble connecting to whatever internet sites for a while, and your browser is waiting for data. That can happen in your wifi, router, modem, neighbourhood network, ISP, or further "upstream"... It would be hard to compare it to a different OS on the same computer, since it probably takes longer than 30 seconds to shutdown & reboot in windows & connect to the exact same site.

You could try `ping`-ing a reliable site that responds (like www.google.com or www.yahoo.com) and see if you start dropping pings or they take a lot longer when having the problem. The site could be in a different "direction" from the ones that aren't responding so it may or may not help.

Or is your browser, or whole system, completely freezing & you can't even open menus or anything? That would be something completely different

Comment: Thanks, your first sentence is correct. When it happens I try to ping google.com but get no replies. AND I try the same site from my laptop (running Ubuntu) and it connects flawlessly. So I think it must be the current OS. How can I narrow the problem down? The system doesn't freeze, but I can't connect to any site (when the connection is frozen)

Comment: Hmmm, laptop on the same router works, while at exact same time desktop doesn't, and windows is OK. Could be there's something about the way the desktop connects to the router - wired should be most reliable (unless wire's pinched or moving or something), wifi is always suspect. But maybe hardware config / **driver** intermittent problems (hardest type to find, never reliably happen or stop). If swapping a wifi or lan adapter is possible that's a good test, or try a different kernel or Ubuntu version or even distro, sometimes they're more or less compatible with hardware